# How to restore pg_dump file into postgres database

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

So I regularly backup and restore databases and schema's using pgadmin4. I would like to do it with a batch file using commands as pg_dump and pg_restore. I however always fail to succeed in this and could use some help. The way I try to dump one schema (with data) is the following:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -F c -d database -n schema > mw2
```

Then I try to restore it with pg_restore:

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d otherdatabase -n schema mw2
```

First I tried to use .dump in stead of tar but the result stays the same; which is an empty schema in my database.

Or the following error message:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html

> --format=format  Specify format of the archive. It is not necessary to specify the format, since pg_restore will determine the format
>   automatically. If specified, it can be one of the following:

**custom, directory and tar**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

--format=format

> Selects the format of the output. format can be one of the following:
>
> p plain Output a plain-text SQL script file (the default).

others are **custom, directory and tar**

in short - you used defualt **plain** format, which is meant for using with `psql`, not `pg_restore`. So either specify different format with `pg_dump` or use your file as

```
psql -f  mw2.tar
```

Comment: Trying it out now by adding -F t in the dump

Comment: It does execute now; but the resulting schema stays empty. Still doesnt work; ill update my code

Comment: Looking into psql -f mw2.tar now, but I first need to select the right database and schema there.

Comment: Please don't mess the POST. If you have different problem now - try finding the solution between existing posts, you there's none - ask a new question

Comment: @Zuenie yes - surely, like `psql -U postgres -d otherdatabase -f mw2`. I mentioned only `-f` key as it is different

Comment: it just adds a new schema in your existing database. I thought I had to select a schema in the database so that psql knows where to restore it. Got it now; working like a charm!